# Rally integration with SharePoint

Tags: api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, rally, rallyapi

Is it possible to get rally data to SharePoint online list by doing a Rest API call or is there a way to integrate rally to SharePoint.
Please let me know the available option

Answer (score 0):

One option is to write a custom app, create an API Key and embed it into sharepoint via an iFrame.

More details can be found in the SDK Docs: https://rally1.rallydev.com/docs/en-us/saas/apps/2.1/doc/index.html#!/guide/embedding_apps-section-develop-the-app

Edit: I should note that you need to find a way to obscure the apiKey from users. The apiKey should only have read access and should be completely hidden

Comment: I am referring to embedding dashboard (not individual report).and also navigation between embedded rally projects in SharePoint online.

Comment: That seems very complex. I doubt there's a feasible way to accomplish that from both a technology and a security perspective.